# parsing an html view of an xml file with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some simple data from an XML file that is only accessible as an HTML page.

```
import requests
import pprint
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:massive-attack"
resp = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')
something = soup.find_all(string="artist")
metadata = soup.select("#folder0 > div:nth-child(1)")
beginarea = soup.select("#folder3 > div.opened > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)")
print(something)
```

Whenever I try to select an element and print its contents, I get []. I've tried selector and the BeautifulSoup search methods, as well as parsing it as an XML file with ElementTree. What am I missing here? I can't seem to get any data from the page at all.
Thank you.

Comment: Try `soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "lxml")` let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = [x.text for x in soup.select('area + name')]
    print(goal)


main('https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:massive-attack')
```

Output:

```
['Bristol', 'United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Australia', 'Sweden', 'New Jersey', 'Japan', 'France', 'United Kingdom', 'Australia', 'United Kingdom', 'Germany', 'United States', 'Germany', 'United Kingdom', 'France', 'Quebec']
```

Comment: thank you SO MUCH!! this works!